# Dragging a ListBoxItem that contains a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a list box full of objects and i have implemented a drag and drop to reorder them. the objects have the following format:

[image]   Label   [______TextBox_____]  Textblock

everything works great except if you start the drag on the textbox, or the drag goes over the textbox I get the no cursor, dragging around anywhere else works as expected.

I have the textbox's `PreviewDragEnter` and `PreviewDragOver` both subscribed to the following handler:

```
    private void Preview_DragEnter_Handler(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
        e.Handled = true;
        //update adorner positions      
    }
```

Dropping works just fine even if i am over one of the textboxes. with the `no cursor`
How can i get rid of the `No cursor` when dragging my object over the textbox's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting `isHitTestVisable = false` on the textbox solved my problem!